# Spring Security Oauth - Basic access authentication needed when sending token request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security

I've got one problem with Spring Security OAuth 2.0.

There is basic configuration of spring-security, taken from sample:

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<http pattern="/path/**" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/path/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="path" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="path/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationProvider" class="my.package.OAuthAuthenticationProvider" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" />

<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider ref="oauthAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="userApprovalHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />
</bean>

<!-- authorization-server aka AuthorizationServerTokenServices is an interface 
    that defines everything necessary for token management -->
<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    user-approval-handler-ref="userApprovalHandler">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
    resource-id="test" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />
<!-- ClientsDeailsService: Entry Point to clients database (given is in 
    memory implementation) -->
<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <!-- client -->
    <oauth:client client-id="the_client"
        authorized-grant-types="authorization_code,client_credentials"
        authorities="ROLE_USER" scope="read,write,trust" secret="secret" />

    <oauth:client client-id="my-trusted-client-with-secret"
        authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit"
        secret="somesecret" authorities="ROLE_USER" />

</oauth:client-details-service>

<sec:global-method-security
    pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
    <sec:expression-handler ref="oauthExpressionHandler" />
</sec:global-method-security>

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```

It works, when in my web.xml file looks like this:

```
...
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
...
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
...
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
...
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
...
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
...
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But in this case, the "old part" of system doesn't work. 
So I have to change Dispatcher Servlet mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/somepath/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now the old part works, but not Oauth Spring security. I've tried with two url-patterns:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/somepath/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then oauth works, old part doesn't.

I did one more try and changed:

```
<http pattern="/somepath/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/somepath/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>
```

And now it works like this:

1. I'm accessing address (which worked before):

   https://localhost.server:8443/system/somepath/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=my-trusted-client-with-secret&client_secret=somesecret&username=user&password=pass
2. Web browser asks for login and password (Basic access authentication).
3. I need to enter client-id in login field and secret in password field.
4. Request to oauth is generated and then authentication method in my.package.OAuthAuthenticationProvider is called.

What should I change to avoid this Basic auth prompt?

Answer (score 2):

Your problems with the servlet and filter mappings stem from the fact that Spring OAuth needs a DispatcherServlet for its OAuth related endpoints. I recommend you put those in the default servlet mapping (/), but it's up to you. In any case your one-stop-shop security configuration is a servlet configuration file, not a root context (so you need to load it with a `DispatcherServlet` not a `ContextLoaderListener`). This would be the same as in the sample (you need a servlet init param in web.xml), but there is nothing to stop you adding your own additional servlets (as long as the mappings don't clash of course).

The authentication question is different. The OAuth2 spec recommends that the /token endpoint is secured with Basic Authentication, so the prompt is a good thing in principle, although I can see that you tried to avoid it.  Putting secrets in form fields like you are doing is not really secure enough to be used in a production system, but if for some reason you need it you can use the `ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter` (as you did).  The reason that filter is not working might have been because you are sending a GET (not a POST), which is an even worse idea for security purposes than using the filter in the first place, but I don't see the flag being set anywhere that switches on POST-only validation in the filter (although I recommend you set it if you use this thing in anger anywhere).

You haven't shown 2 Spring XML files but your web.xml refers to 2. I think the problem ultimately will be traceable to the fact that your have them mixed up or bean definitions duplicated across the two. Maybe you can clarify that (or switch to loading a single file from the `DispatcherServlet` as recommended above)?

Comment: Thank You for your reply.
I'm using spring oauth in another project. I had to use default servlet mapping, but it was possible (the app doesn't run on production :) ). Without spring-security configuration files connected to ContextLoaderListener, spring-security won't start.
But in case of the second app, Basic Authentication didn't ask for client_id and secret, and passing it through GET request parameters was enough for authentication... The same is happening here, when I'll change Dispatcher Servlet Mapping to default one.

Comment: It's not true that Spring Security "won't start" without being loaded as a root context (look at the oauth samples for a counter example). I think I remembered the setting that you haven't enabled which you need for a non-default servlet mapping - the auth and token endpoint urls have to be explicitly set. I need to look again in more detail (tomorrow) and see if I can update the answer with more information, but maybe that will get you started.

Comment: Once again thanks for Your help.
Now I'm using POST method and other way of sending basic auth credentials and it seems to work fine.
How should I set this "POST-only" validator?

Comment: And one more question - how to send token request properly - I need a secure solution. 
Now I've changed only from GET to POST method.
(I'm already using SSL)

Comment: The POST-only validation is in the `ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter`. Better would be to not use that filter at all and use some other more secure authentication for clients (you already have HTTP Basic enabled, whih is why your browser is prompting you in your manual test). Any HTTP client will support Basic auth (check the docs).

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the login page using a configuration like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
            .and()
                .csrf()
                .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**")).disable();
        // @formatter:on
    }
    ...
}
```

By default this method include a login page. With this new implementation in case you try to do a request without token a 403 error page will be displayed (you also can manage this error in order to redirect to a customized page)